# Is the consensus of all scholars a must condition for ijma?

Tags: definitions, ijma

It's clearly proved from hadith of bukhari that not all companions have Ijma to caliphate of Abu bakr when he delivered the sermon after becoming caliph.

https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4240

Imam Shafaee said all scholars need to agree for ijma.

Sk. Utheymeen has similar view.

> Shaykh Ibn ‘Uthaymeen (may Allah have mercy on him) said:
> In linguistic terms, ijmaa‘ means resolve and agreement.
> In shar‘i terms, it means the agreement of the mujtahids of this ummah after the death of the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) on a shar‘i ruling.
> By saying “agreement” we exclude differences of opinion; if there is a difference of opinion, even from one person, then we cannot say that there is ijmaa‘.

Source : https://islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/201682
I see contradiction between election of Abu bakr and view of later scholars including imam ash shafaee. Hence the question is the consensus of all scholars a must condition for ijma

Comment: The hadith itself shows that they eventually agreed to give the oath and accept him as the first Khalifah. Ijmaa does not mean some of the Sahabah may not have had a different opinion before then changed their mind. Even if some of them changed their mind to a position, that is still Ijmaa.

Comment: What is the relevance of the election of Abu Bakr to this topic and how does that define Ijma? There is no need for Ijma to select a caliph, rather the approval of the majority of the  *Ahlul Hal wal Aqd* is enough, and according to some madhabs not even a majority is required, but rather even a small group is enough for appointing a legitimate caliph. Ofcourse the sunni view is that the sahaba all eventually agreed to accept the caliphate of Abu Bakr, the hadith you have cited says the same.

Comment: UmH, I learnt a couple of hours ago that there is no ijma on definition of ijma, also Abu Bakr Al Jassas, a hanafi scholar, defining even a simple majority view as constituting consensus

Comment: Neither the definition of the term ijma' is agreed upon nor do all madhhabs agree on a kind of ijma' beyond that of the sahabah. The hadith shown is in no relation to the topic of ijma', please explain what you intend to have exolained and why you've chosen this hadith. @TheZ I doubt that if a Sahabi uttered his opinion against the view of the majority that their opinion would still be accepted as ijma'.

Comment: @UmH, .

This

”In the Hanbali view the only real Ijma which occurred other than agreement on religious
belief was when the infant Muslim community elected Abu Bakr as the first Caliph
following the death of the Holy Prophet. Dr farooq "the doctrine of ijma"